# Using wildcard charlist in android SQLite interaction

Tags: android, sqlite, wildcard

By this moment I've mentioned that using of wildcard charlist enclosed in square brackets (`[]`) when interact with android's sqlite is possible using `GLOB` statement, but the problem is that it's a case sensitive.

I would like to know is there any way to make `GLOB` case insensitive or some magic way to make `LIKE` statement be able to work with wildcard charlist in Android?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`LIKE` does not support character lists.

You have to duplicate upper and lower case characters in the character list:

```sql
... WHERE Name GLOB '[XYZxyz]*'
```

Comment: So if user wants to find an entry which contains "banana" my query should looks like: `WHERE name GLOB '*[Bb][Aa][Nn][Aa][Nn][Aa]*'`?

Comment: The problem is that LIKE is case insensitive only for ASCII symbols, and you right - here, 'banana' is not a good example. But if I need to work with non-ASCII symbols (cyrillic, for example) using wildcards here is not convenient for me.

Comment: Then you indeed have to use `'*[Bb][Aa][Nn][Aa][Nn][Aa]*`.

Comment: My actual problem is that I need to make equal search for letters 'ё' and 'е' in both upper and lower cases. Now I'm looking for combination of using LIKE with replace() function.